# How can I send bitcoin from my bisq wallets?

Tags: coinbase.com, bisq

I feel terrible to ask this question as it is so basic that it makes me feel stupid to ask, but I am searching the web since days and cannot find an answer.

Here is the situation:
I have a Coinbase account and I understand that Coinbase cannot use different/multiple wallets but has one wallet that cannot be changed.
I also use bisq and I bought a bit of bitcoin there without hassle. However, bisq has distributed my bitcoins to multiple wallets for reasons I do not understand. It has generated countless wallets, most of them empty, but there are still 3 wallets having a bit of money each.

Now I want to sell my bitcoins, but bisq has a number of downsides for selling btc:

- I have a limitation of 0.06 btc. I don't understand why, because I have bisq installed since ages and I thought the limitation would start with 0.25 and grow over time, but anyway, bisq tells me I cannot offer more at a time.
  Selling all my coins at this rate would take ages!
- Since I have two small kids now, I cannot have the computer running all the time (shielding it from the kids) and be there when a buyer comes

What I want is to sell all my funds. The easiest way that I see right now would be to transfer all funds (0.49btc) to my coinbase wallet as from coinbase I can sell any amount of btc whenever I want.

But... I found no way to transfer the BTCs in bisq. In Coinbase there is a function "receive bitcoin" but all it gives me is the wallet id. So, what is the best way to merge/transfer (all) funds from the 3 bisq generated wallets to the coinbase wallet?

Of course, if you have another suggestion on how to sell the funds easily other than through coinbase, I'd be open for that, too.

Cheers,
8bitdefender
btw: I tried to include the tag "bisq" but could not as that would be a new tag

Answer (score 1):

Ah, sorry guys! Now I did find a simple "send bitcoin" function in bisq... I must have been blind!

Still, if you think that my idea to send all btc from all 3 wallets to the coinbase wallet is a bad idea, I'd be happy for your input.